# Javascript Card Game - Replace array item after random select

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am asked to create a game of war game in javascript (everything loads in the alert box).  I have one round in place, but haven't started the loops or the "war' yet until I get the cards to load and score properly.

I am struggling with the non-numbered cards to J, Q, K, etc.

This is a very introductory course and I'm very new to the subject.  Help is greatly appreciated.

Here's my code:

```js
var userName = prompt("what's your name?");

alert("Hi " + userName + ". Let's Play War!");

var computerScore = 26;
var userScore = 26;

var suits = ["Spades", "Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds"];
var cards = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14];

var computerCard = cards[Math.floor(Math.random()*cards.length)];
var computerSuit = suits[Math.floor(Math.random()*suits.length)];
var userCard = cards[Math.floor(Math.random()*cards.length)];
var userSuit = suits[Math.floor(Math.random()*suits.length)];



if (computerCard >= 11 || userCard >= 11)
{
  cards[9] = "Jack";
  cards[10] = "Queen";
  cards[11] = "King";
  cards[12] = "Ace";
}

alert("I drew a " + computerCard + " of " + computerSuit + " and you drew a " + userCard + " of " + userSuit);

  if (computerCard > userCard)
  {
    computerScore++;
    alert("I win. \nThe score is now " + computerScore + " to" + userScore + ".\nDeal Again");
  }
  else
  {
  userScore++;
  alert("You win. \nThe score is now " + computerScore + " to" + userScore + ".\nDeal Again");
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? What does work, what doesn't? What have you tried?

Comment: I set a computerCard and userCard variable that randomly select a number from  the cards array.  

If the number 11-14 is chosen randomly for computerCard or userCard, I need it to display as Jack, Queen, King, Ace respectively when the alert shows what was drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is some way to associate the display value of a card, say "7" or "Jack" with its point value, respectively 7 or 11.  Perhaps the most explicit way of doing so is to create something like this:

```js
const cardValues = {'2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9,
                    '10': 10, 'Jack': 11, 'Queen': 12, 'King': 13, 'Ace': 14}
```

But such is not the only way to do this, and it may in fact be a bit more difficult to use with the code you already have.  The fact that you only need to compare the values to see which is larger, and you don't actually need those explicit values suggests an easier structure, a simple array

```js
const cards = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace']
```

Then you can use `computerIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length);` and `computerCard = cards[computerIndex]`, doing the same with `userIndex` and `userCard` and then replace your comparison with `if (computerIndex > userIndex)`

This is by no means the only way of doing something like this.  But I think it's the simplest working change to your current code.